# Compare only first number of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I am looking for a way to only compare the first number of a 3 number tuple.  For example let's say I have this tuple: `a = (255, 100, 200)` and this tuple `b = (255, 10, 20)`. If I were to check if they were equal using:

```
if a == b:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("unequal")
```

Then I would obviously get `unequal` since they are not the same. But the first number is the same, how would I be able to compare **only** the first number so that I would get `equal` printed using these tuples?

Comment: highly suggest going back to docs and looking up how to index objects in python

Comment: and if you were comparing first element in list of tuples like `[(a1, a2, a3), (a1, a2, a3), (a1, a2, a3), ...]` you can compare `[a[0] for a in rows]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if a[0] == b[0]:
    print('equal')
```

tuples can be indexed the same as lists in Python, but are immutable unlike lists!